# reverse words BUT dot should be at the end

Tags: c#

I have sentence: 
"I love Marry." 
and I would like to get: 
"Marry love I." (dot at the end)

How can I do that?

```
public static string ReverseWords(string originalString)
{
   return string.Join(" ", originalString.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Reverse());
}
```

Comment: Add `+ "."` to the end after `Reverse()`?

Comment: What about text with multiple sentence like "Line one. Line two."?

Comment: @CoderJoe and then`.Substring(1)` to get rid of the dot at the front.

Comment: Can you add more examples of input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the last '.' before the split.

Demo:

```
public static string ReverseWords(string originalString)
{
    var input = originalString.EndsWith(".") ? originalString.Remove(originalString.Length - 1) : originalString; // will trim ending '.'
    return string.Join(" ", input.Split().Reverse()) + ".";
}
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iwARoM)

Answer (score 0):

For single sentences, remove the dot and append it again in the end.
To remove the dot you can use `TrimEnd` which will remove all dots from the end of the string. If there is none, nothing is removed:

```
    public static string ReverseWords(string originalString)
    {
        originalString = originalString.TrimEnd('.');
        originalString = string.Join(" ", originalString.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Reverse());

        return originalString + ".";
    }
```

For multiple senctences you can split the input string at the `.`, which will give you an array of sentences without dots. Then you simply reverse each part, append a dot and put them back together (I used a `StringBuilder` to do that):

```
    public static string ReverseWordsMultiple(string originalString)
    {
        String[] sentences = originalString.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (String senctence in sentences)
        {
            builder.Append(string.Join(" ", senctence.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Reverse()));
            builder.Append(". ");
        }

        return builder.ToString().TrimEnd();
    }
```

Comment: be careful with `TrimEnd()`. if the input is `Hello World..`, you will have `World Hello.` instead of `World Hello..`. Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654511/1248177)  for an alternative.

Comment: That is true. Actually BOTH methods will remove all additional dots.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am making it into several statements for readability.

```
var words = originalString.Split(new [] {' ', '.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Reverse();
```

That gets your words in reverse order, and avoids the need for your `Where` clause. Then join them back with the period:

```
return string.Join(' ', words) + '.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps where you split on `.` first;

```
return 
    string.Join(".",
         originalString.Split('.')
            .ToList()
            .Select(s => string.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Reverse())));
```

Comment: You dont need to `.ToList()` and `Split()` can be use without `' '`.